# How to use GCP Runtime Configurator from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, runtime-configuration

I'm working on a Node.js application hosted on Google Cloud, using [Google Application Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/). The app has a few settings like the following:

```js
const TASK_BATCH_SIZE = 50;
```

Currently, every time we need to change some settings like that one to do some tests we need to re-deploy the app, and that happens very often. We are looking for some alternatives inside the Google Cloud ecosystem that allows us to configure our running services without needing to re-deploy.

One of the things we found in the docs was [Runtime Configurator](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator/), which still seems to be a beta product. For Node.js specifically  [nodejs-rcloadenv](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-rcloadenv) is the only client library we found, but doesn't seem to support the *Watcher* / *Waiter* concepts described in the Runtime Configurator docs or any other way to subscribe to variable changes in a configuration resource.

Is Runtime Configurator the solution to our problem? Are there any other services inside the Google Cloud ecosystem, or any other library for Node.js that could help us with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update or to make some settings changes in the service, you need to re-delpoy the service.

You can't use [Runtime Configurator](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator/) as it's for Compute Engine and not for App Engine.

You can create a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/) on Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) for your issue ( to update configurations without re-deploying the service).